# Execute sql statement as sys as sysdba

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, sysdba

I have a sql statement executed in a script which connects to sqlplus and execute some GRANTS statements. In the bash script the instruction is something like:

```
sqlplus sys as sysdba @script.sql
```

but I need to add the password. How can I do in a single line ?

I tried:

```
sqlplus "sys as sysdba"/password @script.sql
```

or without " but it does not work.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example 1

```
oracle@esmd:~> sqlplus /  as sysdba @ulcase1.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Fri Feb 21 12:07:50 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
oracle@esmd:~>
```

Example 2

```
oracle@esmd:~> sqlplus sys/password  as sysdba @ulcase1.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Fri Feb 21 12:08:44 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
oracle@esmd:~>
```

Example 3

```
oracle@esmd:~> sqlplus sys/password@esmd  as sysdba @ulcase1.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Fri Feb 21 12:14:49 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
oracle@esmd:~>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute it on this way:

```
sqlplus sys/password as sysdba @script.sql
```